# Create bloc instance for named route + pass arguments

Tags: flutter, parameter-passing, flutter-bloc, named-routing

My app uses FlutterBloc for state management. My use case:

- list of items loaded from rest web service
- on each item tap I need to load item details and display them on new page.

My code to show details page on list item tap:

```
return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => BlocProvider(
              create: (_) => DetailsBloc(
                someRepository: context.read<SomeRepository>(),
                otherRepository context.read<OtherRepository>(),
              )..add(GetItemDetailsEvent(id: item.id.toString())),
              child: const EventDetailsPage(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Card(....)
```

It works fine. On each list item tap, it shows new page and provides new `DetailsBloc` instance to its context. After page is closed, bloc will be destroyed as well (this is how I want it to work). `DetailsBloc` includes event to load details data by item id, so details window is able to refresh itself to show details.

But I prefer to use named routes and use `pushNamed` instead. I am able to provide new `DetailsBloc` instance this way when route is created and optionally, send event to it:

```
'/item_details': (context) => BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => DataBloc(
                  someRepository: SomeRepository(),
                  otherRepository: OherRepository(),
                )..add(GetItemDetailsEvent(id: <id>),
                ,
               child: const DetailsPage()),
```

This way, I can show new page by `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/item_details');` But in this case, I see no way to pass id to event to load data, because it's not known when route initialises itself. So I can't add event in route definition. I could try to add event later, on list item tap:

```
onTap: () {
 context.read<DetailsBloc>().add((GetItemDetailsEvent(id: item.id.toString());
```

This obviously won't work, because `DetailsBloc` is not provided here and it even does not exist anywhere before route is created. I can also add event to `DetailsBloc` inside my `DetailsPage` but it must be done in inside init state, so:

- my details page widget needs to be stateful which I want to avoid
- even if details page widget is stateful, I can't read route arguments inside init state to pass it to bloc's event. So basically, I'm stuck and I see no way to use named route in this case.

Do you have any ideas how to use named route here?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the id in router arguments:

```
await Navigator.pushNamed(
                context,
                DetailsPage.routeName,
                arguments: id,
              );
```

then in the route_builder:

```
...
case DetailsPage.routeName:
        final arguments = settings.arguments as String;
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => DetailsPage(itemId: arguments),
          settings: settings,
        );        
...
```

and finaly in the DetailsPage:

```
class DetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const DetailsPage({
    required this.itemId,
    super.key,
  });

  static const routeName = '/details_page';
  final int storyId;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => BlocProvider<DetailsBloc>(
        create: (context) => DetailsBloc(
            someRepository: SomeRepository(),//or get it from DI or ServiceLocator
            otherRepository: OtherRepository(),//or get it from DI or ServiceLocator
          )..add(GetItemDetailsEvent(id: item.id.toString())),
        child: const DetailsPageView(),
      );
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was my idea too. But I don't like I am forced to use `onGenerateRoute` instead `routes` param and also I am forced to create bloc instance inside `build` override

Comment: first of all, onGenerateRoute is created for ability to passing the arguments in to the widget. so, you have no ability to pass value in your case as you also mention, that DetailsBloc is not exist before route is created and you don't want it behave that way..  not realy understand why you don't like onGenerateRoute. 
as a crutches :) you always could store id in sharedpreferences and retrive it when you need it :)

Comment: `you always could store id in sharedpreferences and retrive it when you need it ` - it does not make any sense, as id changes on every list item tab. You are right, `onGenerate` route is not as bad. But details widget is more complicated + creating bloc instance inside build method is very bad, because build method is not guaranted to execute only one time

Comment: a little bit very strange statement:
"creating bloc instance inside build method is very bad, because build method is not guaranted to execute only one time"

from this logic we got:
creating ANY WIDGET instance inside build method of parent is very bad, because build method is not guaranted to execute only one time %:)


BlocBuilder is just a Flutter widget. 
more info: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts

Comment: Yes, it is. But I actually don't want to create new state on every widget build, because I only need to provide and inject bloc to context only once. Don't you really feel it's not safe to create new bloc instance inside build method? In my opinion - get value: ok, create instance - not really. Worst scenerio possible: create bloc instance + add event that rebuilds widget and we get endless loop

Comment: to be honest, not a bit!
Flutter builds its user interface to reflect the current state and we have build method. As said above we create just anouther widget (BlocProvider etc) that deal with other type of entity - streams, that either cubit or bloc has under the hood. of course, this is a simplified scheme. but flutter is smart enough to handle widget tree and there no any any side effects in this case. very strange to use a block but not agree with how it works )) 
I think it is possible to loop the app execution even with a regular setState(), but this doesn't make it bad or incorrect.

Comment: Ok, but I need to get my bloc instance persistent while page exists, including page itself. So I don't really want to provide bloc for child (content) widget, I rather preffer to provide it for my page context, outside the page. So preffered sequence: list item tap->create bloc->create details page and context.select<DetailsBloc> inside page build method (or any child widget's build) to refreresh content. I don't want to mess with blocs creation inside page build method, I preffer to have them alreade injected into context.

Comment: There may be multiple blocs provided to page's context to access data (context.read()) or list for changes (context.wath() or context.select) - for page itself or any child widget